# Creating a hyperlink to call Torrent client softwares

Tags: html, hyperlink, bittorrent

I know that using code `<a href="mailto:john.smith@gmail.com">John Smith</a>` I can call email clients to send emails to who I want.

Now, how can I call torrent client softwares to download a torrent?

Comment: I think this can be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479570/given-a-torrent-file-how-do-i-generate-a-magnet-link-in-python

I think you'll need to do this server side. The above link is for Python. I'm sure you could find an equivalent for whichever language  your server is in.

Comment: My god, @keithxm23 I thought that there should be a standard for all those softwares. OK, thank you. So what does `href="magnet:http://link"` will do? Someone commented that I had to use `magnet` but deleted it shortly after the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you are not *calling* an email client when a user clicks on such a link. Instead, the client launches the application registered for handling that type of URI. The technical name for the `mailto` part of the URI is the [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

What you actually want is the [Magnet URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme).

To generate a BitTorrent magnet URI, you need to extract the `info` section of the bencoded .torrent file contents, as described in [the BitTorrent protocol specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html). Generate the SHA-1 hash of the data (this is called the "infohash"), then hex-encode that hash. You can also include a `tr` parameter to declare where the tracker is. e.g.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:<your_hex_encoded_sha1_hash>&tr=http://urlto/announce
```

For further reading, I would suggest [How do BitTorrent magnet links work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844502/how-does-bt-magnet-links-work).

Answer (score -1):

you could use a magnet link

(this is a example for a file with 0bytes)

```
   magnet:?xt=urn:ed2k:31D6CFE0D16AE931B73C59D7E0C089C0
&xl=0&dn=zero_len.fil
&xt=urn:bitprint:3I42H3S6NNFQ2MSVX7XZKYAYSCX5QBYJ
.LWPNACQDBZRYXW3VHJVCJ64QBZNGHOHHHZWCLNQ
&xt=urn:md5:D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
```

then you can personalize your magnetic link to managing the downloading for the file that you want to be downloaded.

source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#Technical_description