# Ruby Magnet link from torrent file

Tags: ruby, bittorrent, base32, magnet-uri

How do I generate a magnet link from a given torrent file?
Similar to this: [Given a .torrent file how do I generate a magnet link in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479570/given-a-torrent-file-how-do-i-generate-a-magnet-link-in-python)

Extra points if you explain how magnet links work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for it too

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this script: [A ruby script to construct magnet links out of .torrent files](https://gist.github.com/Burgestrand/1733611)

Also, a relevant Stack Overflow question: [How do BitTorrent magnet links work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844502/how-do-bittorrent-magnet-links-work)