# Downloading file from S3 using magnet link

Tags: amazon-s3, magnet-uri

S3 supports file distribution via BitTorrent protocol. If I download **.torrent** file adding **?torrent** to the link, I will be able to download file using uTorrent, for example. But I can't download the same file using magnet link.

I'm creating magnet link as described in this topic [Given a .torrent file how do I generate a magnet link in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479570/given-a-torrent-file-how-do-i-generate-a-magnet-link-in-python). I'm trying to download the file as **magnet:?xt=urn:btih:hash** and with specified tracker **magnet:?xt=urn:btih:hash&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.amazonaws.com%3A6969%2Fannounce**. In both cases it didn't work in different torrent clients.

Is it possible to download a file from S3 using magnet link ?